# How to assign equation solutions to variables

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, variable

I have 12x12 Matrix with which I have to solve the equation below:

```
redK.{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12} == {3, 5, 7, 1, 6, 19, 12, 0, 0, 6, 2, 1}
```

I solve them using:

```
Solve[%112, {x1, x10, x11, x12, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}]
```

For which I get following solutions:

```
{{x1 -> 6.99501*10^-8, x10 -> 1.5303*10^-7, x11 -> 1.44794*10^-9, 
  x12 -> -1.38326*10^-8, x2 -> 1.66228*10^-8, x3 -> -1.29556*10^-8, 
  x4 -> 8.525*10^-8, x5 -> 9.60869*10^-10, x6 -> 2.32703*10^-8, 
  x7 -> 1.50191*10^-7, x8 -> 2.35881*10^-8, x9 -> -1.33567*10^-8}}
```

Now, what would be the easiest way to assign these values to the variables with the same name?

Comment: solution/. Rule -> Set

Comment: I have voted to close this as it's part of the answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706)

Comment: FWIW, in my opinion, it is better to (learn how to) use the solutions in the form that `Solve` returns.  It took me a few years to get used to it, but I came to realize how convenient it is to keep my variables (i.e. the symbols of my algebraic formulas) clear of values. It save headaches. It is easy to plug the values into an expression with [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`expr /. solution`).

Comment: If you're just interested in the numbers in the solution of this linear equation, consider using [`LinearSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearSolve.html).